# Mongo query to get nested key value presence

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, find, mongodb-query

I have documents in one of my collections as listed below.

```
  {"id":"1", "properties":{"type1":{"items":[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"}]}}}
    {"id":"2", "properties":{"type2":{"tasks":[{"name":"X"},{"name":"Y"}, {"name":"Z"}]}}}
    {"id":"3", "properties":{"type3":{"categories":[{"name":"A"},{"name":"P"}, {"name":"Q"}, {"name":"R"}]}}}
    {"id":"4", "properties":{"type4":{"list":[{"name":"D"},{"name":"B"}, {"name":"C"}, {"name":"A"}]}}}
```

Can I write a Mongo find query to list me all the documents that contain "name":"A" ? Please let me the efficient way to do it.

I could think of a possibility of creating Criteria with all possible combinations and putting them as an OR condition. But I am not sure of the efficiency and performance.

Any leads on the right and efficient approach to get the list of such documents with dynamic keys and nested combinations would be highly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: May I know why this question is given -1? Is this invalid ?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the different key names at each step of nesting, there is no direct method to check for documents containing "name": "A". You will have to write the correct steps for each document. Like for document 1 you will have to write

```
db.f1.find({"properties.type1.items.name":"A"})
```

and then only it will show document 1. So, to check all documents, you will have to use $OR, like I used here for document 1 and document 3.

```
db.f1.find({$or:[{"properties.type1.items.name":"A"},{"properties.type3.categories.name":"A"}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<String> getKeys(Document it1) throws JSONException {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> resultTemp;
        String temp;
        Document doc;
        JSONArray jsa;

        int len, i;
        System.out.println(it1);
        String js = it1.toJson();
        JSONObject js1 = new JSONObject(js);

        Iterator<String> keys = js1.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            if (key.equals("_id")) {
                result.add(key);
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(key);

            temp = js1.get(key).toString();
            if (temp.contains(":")) {

                jsa = new JSONArray(temp);
                len = jsa.length();
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsa.getJSONObject(i);
                    doc = Document.parse(object.toString());
                    System.out.println(doc);
                    resultTemp = getKeys(doc);
                    for (String keyTemp : resultTemp) {
                        if (!result.contains(key + "." + keyTemp))
                            result.add(key + "." + keyTemp);
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                result.add(key);
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```